# Is it possible to repair a newer lithium ebike battery with freezing damage?

Tags: battery, repair

I leant my bike to a family member, and he put it out of use for the winter. Unbeknownst to me, he left the battery outside in -40°F weather all winter. I came to pick the bike up this following fall and the bike wouldn't start, showing no battery.... I charged it for over 24 hours and wonder if it's possible to fix the darned thing. The battery costs twice as much as the bike: should I dispose of it, try to fix it myself, or bring it to a repair shop?

Comment: Buy a new battery or another bike.

Comment: Tell the family member to buy you a new battery or another bike..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't revive the battery, especially if it was charged when cold its dead for sure. Just recycle it correctly. If you want to get new bike or replace your battery it's up to you. Just keep in mind this battery is dead and can even explode if you try to revive it via some fishy method.

Comment: *noted* this answer is temporarily approved: more information will come available as I verify the information with additional sources, and this comment will be replaced with a *verified* comment or a replacement answer.  So far, based on my reading, I have substantial cause to believe this answer is absolutely correct.